# Audio player that plays throughout the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, audio

I am trying to implement a feature on our wordpress site. Since the site is wordpress, we do have access to the plugins but our site is actually pretty custom and as a developer I do feel comfortable implementing code.

The feature we are trying to implement is similar to these sites:
http://www.premiumbeat.com/royalty_free_music/most_popular

http://99percentinvisible.org/

The audio player continues to play even as you navigate the site. Queuing is not as important to us but the ability to play while navigating the site would be great. I do realize we can have a popup player but we like the idea of on that is sticky to the bottom of the page. Anyway to do this?

Comment: If you want it to continue playing as you navigate through the site, the site will have to be implemented as a single page application-type site that uses pushState to change the url as your navigate from page to page, otherwise getting the audio to seamlessly play while changing pages will require the audio be on a different browser tab.

Comment: not easy to do, unless you make a new site from scratch that's completely modular (ie no init scripts on a single page load). wordpress is not designed for this, it's designed to provide RESTfull article access, and that means a lot of url navigation. you can start by SPAing a subsection and expand out, if the site is too big to redo from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The site that you are using as an example happens to be a single-page application. Unfortunately, you'll have to implement your entire site as a SPA if you want to keep the radio playing seamlessly between page loads. Using a traditional site structure means that the music will inevitably stop playing between page loads.

You can store the state of the player in localStorage and continue playing where you left off, but that's as close to seamless as you can get without making the site a SPA.

Edit: alternatively, you can have the page open up a new tab that plays your music and responds to ajax calls from your main page. That might be a problem if the user disables popups on your site.